# Laravel Database 'Where' statement breaks Search

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have been having a problem with the `where` statement in Laravel. I use this to get data from the database and then push it for live search:

```
$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
    ->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
```

I need to add this to filter the results coming from the database: `->where('site', $site_code)`.

I tried adding it the `where` statement I have above, but it broke my live search and resulted in a 500 server error when I tried typing something in my input. I can use `->where('site', $site_code)` to just display the data from the database but not search it.

My question is: Why does the `->where('site', $site_code)` query break the search and how would you fix it?

***EDIT:*** My controller snippet:

```js
if ($request->ajax()) 
{
    $output="";
    $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
        ->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    if ($launchsitesatellite)
    {
        foreach ($launchsitesatellite as $key => $launchsitesatellites) {
        $output .='<tr>'.
                '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->satname.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->norad_cat_id.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->object_type.'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
else {
    $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('site', $site_code)->get();

    return view('pages/launchsite-filter', compact('launchsites', 'launchsitesatellite'));        
}
}
```

Comment: Where's the semicolon to terminate where `$launchsitesatellite` gets defined (or is it a copy-paste error)?

Comment: @ChrisForrence - Sorry, forgot to add one in for the snippet. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the code you have in your if-block:

```
if ($request->ajax()) 
{
    $output="";
    $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
        ->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    if ($launchsitesatellite)
    {
        foreach ($launchsitesatellite as $key => $launchsitesatellites) {
        $output .='<tr>'.
                '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->satname.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->norad_cat_id.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->object_type.'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

The error you're getting (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446968/laravel-database-where-statement-breaks-search#comment77855874_45447000)) is

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$satname
```

When you define `$launchsitesatellite`, you're adding where-clauses into the SQL statement, but never kick it off.

Instead, do this:

```
$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
    ->orWhere('satname', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
    ->orWhere('norad_cat_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to isolate `or` statements. Try this:

```
$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
    ->where(function($q) use ($request) {
        $q->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
          ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
    })
    ->where('site', $site_code)->get();
```

Comment: I think he meant `WHERE site = ? AND (satname LIKE '%?%' OR norad_cat_id = '%?%')`.

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. I will post my full controller as maybe there might be something conflicting.

Comment: Any errors? Or this doesn't filter the results as you need?

Comment: @Laerte Whenever I search I get a 500 internal server error. Other than that there is nothing.

Comment: @D.777KLM Anything in the error log? (Laravel's log is stored in `storage/logs/laravel.log` by default, or it may be on in your server's error_log)

Comment: So, I think the problem is not related to the query. As Chris said, take a look at the logs, it should help.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yes I get an error - `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$satname`. They are defined in my controllers so something must be going wrong here.

Comment: I was getting the error because I was not adding `->get()` to the query. Once I added that it got rid of the error.

Comment: I'll add it to the answer for future readers, but, it is nice to see that Chris was able to help you with this!